# ayuda con matriz en laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hola tengo el siguiente error con laravel 5.4 cuando creo una matriz para ir agregando elementos y mostrarlos en una tabla
este es el codigo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando hago click en agregar me dice lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo lo hago con ajax pero no me deja crear la matriz alguien pordria ayudarme se le agradeceria

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente, lo que hiciste es crear un offset con el tipo array, lo que es ilegal. Solamente puedes tener offsets del tipo string e integer.

Ejemplo:

```
$array = array();
=> []
$counter = array();
=> []
$array[$counter] = 'test';
PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type on line 1
```

Primero tienes:

```
$acumulador = array();
```

y luego tienes

```
$acumulador++;
```

Te recomiendo inicializar tu variable `$acumulador` a un número entero.

```
$acumulador = 0;
```